# "Unable to launch event error" when opening .ics file from browser or downloads

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, chrome-for-android, google-calendar

I have a Nexus tablet running Android version 5.0.1, Chrome 60, and Google Calendar 5.7

I'm unable to view .ics calendar files when downloaded from a website.  These .ics files work on every other device tested.  I know this was an issue for Google Calendar 5.0.1, but it was supposed to be fixed in 5.1.  I've also read that this issue has since resurfaced in more recent updates.  Is there a workaround to get .ics files to work?